# How to use JWT auth from API with Nebular Auth

Tags: angular, jwt, nebular, ngx-admin

i'm using nebular auth for my angular app, i want to add token when user login to header
here's the API response

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "message": null,
  "data": {
    "type": "bearer",
    "token": "string"
  }
}
```

And in my auth.module

```
NbAuthModule.forRoot({
      strategies: [
        NbPasswordAuthStrategy.setup({
          name: 'email',
          token: {
            class: NbAuthJWTToken,
            key: 'data.token', 
          },
          baseEndpoint: 'http://api.mydomain.com/api',
          login: {
            redirect: {
              success: '/pages/project/all-project',
              failure: null
            },
            endpoint: '/login',
            method: 'post',
          },
          register: {
            endpoint: '/register',
            method: 'post',
          },
          logout: {
            endpoint: '/auth/sign-out',
            method: 'post',
          },
          requestPass: {
            endpoint: '/auth/request-pass',
            method: 'post',
          },
          resetPass: {
            endpoint: '/auth/reset-pass',
            method: 'post',
          },
        }),
      ],
      forms: {},
    }),
```

I succesfully logged in but there is no token in header, how can i add that when user login?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, to add a token to the header, you need to create an interceptor. This interceptor will retrieve the token and assign it to the header. For example:

`auth-interceptor.ts`

```
import { HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { NbAuthJWTToken, NbTokenService } from '@nebular/auth';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private tokenService: NbTokenService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    // Add Bearer token to request headers
    return this.tokenService.get().pipe(
      switchMap((jwtToken: NbAuthJWTToken) => {
        const token = jwtToken.getValue();
        const authReq = req.clone({
          setHeaders: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token },
        });

        return next.handle(authReq);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Add `auth-interceptor` to the `app.module.ts`:

```
providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true },
]
```